# LWC Display or not display but looking up a field on the current logged in community user's Account (its a checkbox)

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, lightning-community

I have an LWC component and I need to check a custom field's value on the Account object (the field is a checkbox) and if it is checked - DONT show a html button... but if its unchecked - SHOW an HTML button.

This is for a LWC component on a page inside our Community. So it would be the logged in user's Account.

Any ideas?

```
import ACCOUNT_ID from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Client_ID__c';
import ACCOUNT_IM from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Identity_Management_Configured__c';


export default class EnrollButton extends LightningElement {
    
    userId = USER_ID;
    accountId = ACCOUNT_ID;
    
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId : "$userId", fields: [USER_NAME, USER_LANGUAGE]})
    user;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId : "$accountId", fields: [ACCOUNT_IM]})
    account;

    get userFrench()
    {
        if (getFieldValue(this.user.data, USER_LANGUAGE) == 'fr')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    
    get toshow(){

        //return EnrollButtonTF;

        if (getFieldValue(this.account.data, ACCOUNT_IM) == false)
        {
            //return false;            
            return EnrollButtonTF;
        }
        else
        {
            //return EnrollButtonTF;
            return false;
        }        
    }
```

```
<div if:true={toshow} class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:5rem">
        <lightning-button
            class="button"
            label={label.ButtonLabel}
            onclick={handleClick}
            variant="brand"></lightning-button> 
    </div>
    

    <div if:false={toshow} class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-var-m-around_xx-large" style="height:5rem">
    {label.ContactSupport}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just be:

```
get toshow() {
  return !getFieldValue(this.account.data, ACCOUNT_IM) && EnrollButtonTF;
}
```

Note that you're using the wrong variable; you're using a field token instead of the actual Id. Your code should look more like:

```
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import USER_ACCOUNT_ID from '@salesforce/schema/User.AccountId';

...

export default class ... {

    userId = USER_ID;
    user;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId : "$userId", fields: [USER_NAME, USER_LANGUAGE, USER_ACCOUNT_ID]})
    handleUser(result) {
      this.user = result;
      this.accountId = getFieldValue(result.data, USER_ACCOUNT_ID);
    }

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId : "$accountId", fields: [ACCOUNT_IM]})
    account;
```

Comment: Code you posted works... but the button shows whether the ACCOUNT_IM field is checked or not checked. I need the button to show if the field is not checked. If its checked - then dont show.

Comment: `
get toshow() {

        if (!getFieldValue(this.account.data, ACCOUNT_IM))
        {                   
            return EnrollButtonTF;
        }
        else
        {           
            return false;
        }        
      }
`

Comment: @DarrellW I misread your code. Your wires are all messed up. See my new edit. Also, stop trying to return `EnrollButtonTF`? It's not defined anywhere, so of course you'd always get the same result.

Comment: import EnrollButtonTF from  '@salesforce/customPermission/ViewIDPEnrollButton';

Only certain logged in users with this custom permission should see the Enrollment button

Comment: @DarrellW That would be been good to have mentioned, lol. In that case, see my edit.